# W3C Errors - I would like to fix the validation

Tags: w3c

I have been trying for hours to figure out what is wrong with my code (according to W3C validator). I have coded the whole site from scratch using Notepad++ (my first site without templates, sitebuilders and yada). I have a link to a screenshot Again, I am pretty new at all of this and am wondering if the errors could be a mistake on W3C part or if I am over looking something obvious.

Please let me know if you need any other information. I really would like to be validated, with some of your help may be I can.

http://postimg.org/image/t536bqfuv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should check your syntax. The complains it mentions are quite important.
First of all remove the value attribute from your image, then check the entire document for tags you opened but didn't close.

Comment: Ok thanks. Removing the value attribute brought it down to the last 3 errors. So At this point is it likely just an open tag?

Comment: One or more, I can't tell. But yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me get this straightened out Severin. Result:  Passed, 2 warning(s) = Im validated! Appreciate ya.

Comment: No problem. Just mark this question as the right answer if you felt it was helpful.